# PHP-Enqueue Multi queue worker / Thread

Tags: cakephp, php-enqueue

I use Queue plugin for CakePHP which is a wrapper and Queueing libraries for the php-queue queue library.

I wanted to know if it was possible to launch simultaneous workers without executing the same Job several times.

Thanks for your help.

When I run this command twice in a row, the same Job is executed twice.

```
bin/cake queue worker
```